# Weird syntax error (New to Python)

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, function

So I've been following this nice guide at the recommendation of a friend on how to make Bots, it's a bit old having been written in 2010, but it seems to be (mostly) up to date. However 1/4ths the way through, I seem to have been getting this weird syntax error. I know I didn't do anything too different from the original script to request that.

(Lets assume I already have (import win32api, win32co/import os/import time/ as well as h_x = 0/h_y = 0))

I tweaked some values to deal with multiple things, but the error (see comments in the code):

```
import win32api, win32co
import os
import time

h_x = 0
h_y = 0

def mPos_h(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((h_x + cord[0], h_y + cord[1])

// error
def cords_h():   
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    x = x - h_x
    y = y - h_y
```

Comment: Could you please show us the complete stacktrace?

Comment: It's likely that there's a problem right above that line, and the `def` is finally where Python is like “oh wait…something's wrong here.” It might be helpful if you gave the exact error message Python's spitting out and a little of the code above it.

Comment: Can you show at least 5 lines above and below this?

Comment: Extra code added - The only thing I want it to do is display mouse cords, the def above it's purpose is to move the mouse there(haven't made any clicks yet) - But yeah, I'm not even useing that bit yet, just "def cords_h():"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all programmers have experienced, you're missing one closing parentheses here:

```
def mPos_h(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((h_x + cord[0], h_y + cord[1])
```

Should be:

```
def mPos_h(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((h_x + cord[0], h_y + cord[1]))
```

Comment: Notice the parentheses added.

Comment: Now I feel silly, thanks guys

Comment: You should delete the question if you feel silly. Doesn't contribute anything.

Comment: @RyPeck Wrong. That shouldn't be done. He doesn't have to feel silly, it's a perfectly fine question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed

Comment: The extra parentheses clarification is quite good enough reason for the question to stay I suppose.